# Can the Starlet Sniper outfit be worn by male and female characters?

Tags: fallout-76

I've only seen images of the Starlet Sniper outfit being worn on women. Can anyone confirm that men can wear it too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe all clothing in the Fallout series is unisex, but for further evidence, A [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo76/comments/9yp099/starlet_sniper_outfit/) contains an image of a male character wearing the outfit.  So it appears it does not matter if you're male or female.

Image from post:

[image]